# Computing Probability given CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given $$F(x) =\begin{cases}(x-1)^2/4,& 1 < x < 3\\0,& x\le 1\\ 1,& x\ge3\end{cases}$$

Is $P(2 < X < 5) = P(2 < X)$ since $F(x) = 1$ when $x\ge 3$? Also would $P(X = 1.5) = f(1.5) = F'(1.5)$?

Comment: Yes, $P(2<X<5)=P(2<X)$. But $P(X=1.5)=0$

Comment: You are developing a pattern of asking interesting questions, but not showing any of your own work. Not a good strategy for making the best use of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$P(2<X<5) = F_x(5)-F_x(2) = 1 - F_x(2)  $$
On the other hand, $$P(2<X) = 1-P(X<2) = 1 - F_x(X<2)$$
So the first answer is yes. 
But when we are talking about one specific point in a continuous distribution, its probability considered zero as its occurrence will be almost impossible. Assume we have
$$
P(X=1.5) = P(1.5-\epsilon < X < 1.5+\epsilon) = F_x(1.5+\epsilon) - F_x(1.5-\epsilon) 
$$
where $\epsilon$ is very small number. Based on Taylor series expansion $F_x(1.5+\epsilon)$ could be written as
$$
F_x(1.5+\epsilon) = F_x(1.5) + f_x(1.5)(\epsilon) = F_x(1.5) + \epsilon
$$
and $F_x(1.5-\epsilon) = F_x(1.5) - \epsilon $ in the same way. Therefore,
$$
P(X=1.5) =  F_x(1.5) + \epsilon - F_x(1.5) + \epsilon = \epsilon \approx 0
$$
I hope it helps.